# How to isolate this accordion stylesheet from bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I want to use this [accordion](http://accordionslider.com/)
but when I'm adding bootstrap it's becoming ugly. Is there an easy way to mix this accordion stylesheet from bootstrap ?

Comment: Open chrome dev tools and tweak to your heart's content. When it looks like what you want, save the rules written to the inspector stylesheet into your own stylesheet.

Comment: See the link: https://codepen.io/vishnuprasad/pen/MbZqgW

Answer (score 1):

It's because of box-sizing:border-box which is defined in bootstrap. If you don't have any issue with box-sizing overwrite it with another properties of border-box.

```
*{
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
    -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

Comment: sorry I'm noob, where should I put your css above: in the accordion css ?

Comment: yes you can put it in you own custom stylesheet